# SEO Page Ranking - Key words in Reverse Order (blackcat.com vs catblack.com)

Tags: seo, ranking, google-ranking

Say there are two websites:

1) "blackcat.com" that has tonnes of traffic and is well established.
2) "catblack.com" I am considering purchasing

If I buy "catblack.com" will it ALWAYS be outperformed in google searches by the prior due to its traffic, or will I have a chance at being number one? Should I stay away from making such a domain purchase?

Answer (score 0):

Your domain by itself will have little to no impact on whether you can beat `blackcat.com`. It will mostly depend on its content and backlink profile (assuming black cat and cat black are related).